# Excel VBA custom split string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, parsing, csv

I have cells with strings I need to extract information from to eventually paste into other cells. See snipit below.

Structure of the strings:

```
"sub-string part 1 &lt;variable1&gt; sub-string part 2 &lt;variable2&gt; sub-string part 3 &lt;variable3&gt;"
```

I'm looking to split the string into an array so that each `sub-string part` and each `&lt;variable&gt;` are an element of the array. So whatever comes between the angle brackets `&lt;...&gt;` is a variable

```
resultArray(): {"sub-string part 1", "&lt;variable1&gt;", "sub-string part 2", "&lt;variable2&gt;", "sub-string part 3", "&lt;variable3&gt;}
```

Permutation of the strings can go any way:

1. `"sub-string part 1 &lt;variable1&gt; sub-string part 2 &lt;variable2&gt; sub-string part 3 &lt;variable3&gt; sub-string part 4"`
2. `"&lt;variable1&gt; sub-string part 1 &lt;variable2&gt; sub-string part 2 &lt;variable3&gt;"`
3. `"&lt;variable1&gt; sub-string part 1 &lt;variable2&gt; sub-string part 2 &lt;variable3&gt; sub-string part 3"`
4. "this string has no variable" (in this case only one element would return with the entire string)

I can build an array of just the `&lt;variable&gt;`'s using a regEx, but I'm unable to split it so that sub-strings and variables are each an element of the array.

From an excel perspective, I'm trying to automate what gets populated in column B based on column A from the 
[image: attached snipit]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Actually I see no issues using a regex to split that into an array. See Group 1 to 7 in https://regex101.com/r/BGOYSm/2/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing how with my limited knowledge of regEx.  I'm not looking for specific strings like (Your name is ). This could be anything. I don't know what the sub-strings will be and I don't know what the variable names will be between the angle brackets. All I know is that anything starting and ending in anlge brackets is a variable and sort of acts as a delimiter to split my string. The same regEx would need to apply to cells A2 and A8 in above example and yield results in column B. So far, if I use regex \<.*?\> it extracts my variables, but I need to find how to get the rest

Comment: Well even that is possible with a regex: https://regex101.com/r/BGOYSm/3 Note that the regex flag is set to "ungreedy" `/gmU`

Comment: Thanks! This helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a special type of parsing.  First convert:

**<**

to:

**|<**

and then convert:

**>**

to:

**>|**

and then parse using the pipe:

```
Sub SpecialParser()
    Dim s As String, arr
    With ActiveCell
        s = .Value
        s = Replace(Replace(s, "<", "|<"), ">", ">|")
        arr = Split(s, "|")
        .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        If .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then .Offset(0, 1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.